# Asp.net Search function issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, search

I have a simple search function that allows me to search for certain words from different tables.
This is annoying as I feel there is a simple fix i'm not seeing here. Can someone assist? Thank you in advance.

> ViewModel

```
IEnumerable<Owner> Owners {get; set;}
IEnumerable<Car> Cars {get; set;}
```

> Search Method

```
public IEnumerable<ViewModel> Search(string search)
 {
   ViewModel searchVM = new ViewModel();

   return searchVM.Owner.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(search)) || 
          searchVM.Cars.Where(c => c.Model.Contains(search));
 }
```

> Error

```
Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IEnumerable<Owner>' and 
'IEnumerable<Car>'
```

Comment: Your structure is very confusing.  What's populating the properties in `searchVM`?  Do they get populated with *all possible* data in the constructor?  And what are you expecting the method to return?  A single instance of `ViewModel`, or a collection of `ViewModel`s?

Comment: Well the return method should a string. For example, I'd search for a model and I'd get a collection of models associated with the search parameter.

Comment: What is the right way to structure this?

Comment: You have `ViewModel` class with `Owners` and `Cars` properties? What is the type of `searchVM`? What is the model type expected by the view?

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is *very* strange.  But it *looks* as though what you want is just one instance of your `ViewModel` with each property filtered by the search string.

(Note: It's definitely not clear where your `ViewModel` is populating its properties.  Are you just dumping your entire data store in there in its constructor?  That seems... less than ideal. 
 But as for the question being asked...)

Perhaps something like this:

```
public ViewModel Search(string search)
{
    ViewModel searchVM = new ViewModel();

    searchVM.Owner = searchVM.Owner.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(search));
    searchVM.Cars = searchVM.Cars.Where(c => c.Model.Contains(search));

    return searchVM;
}
```

Again, I strongly suspect that you don't fully understand your own data structure here.  This looks like what you're trying to do based on the information we have in the question, though.

Comment: Thank you David for the prompt response. The data is being dumped in a constructor. I am using the repository pattern. Would that help?

Comment: @ChrisH.: Well, if you want all of your data to be in the view model by default and then to filter down properties based on the search input, then I guess this is how you'd do it.

Comment: Yes that was the original idea. I am still learning the ropes here. Thank you very much.